# Grid CustomRenderer view

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, custom-renderer

i'm trying to make custom renderer of my grid so how to make gradient from NativeView it not affecting my grid any idea ?

```
class GridRenderer : ViewRenderer<Grid, UIView>
{
protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{

    base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
    if (Control == null)
    SetNativeControl(UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController.View);


  var gradientLayer = new CAGradientLayer();
    gradientLayer.Frame = Control.Bounds;

    gradientLayer.Colors = new CGColor[] { Color.Black.ToCGColor(), Color.Gray.ToCGColor() };
//no affect !!
Control.Layer.InsertSublayer(gradientLayer, 0);
```

I don't think i can create a Grid custom renderer - the Grid element isn't visual, it's a layout container. but i think i can get access to the view child some how by assigning the rootviewcontroller

Comment: The question is a bit unclear to me. Do you want to have a single gradient for the whole grid or gradients for each element in the grid?

Comment: as we have background for the grid i want to make gradient color to it

Comment: Maybe you can put the Grid inside a ContentView and create a custom renderer for the ContentView?

Comment: you are right but i think its doable on the grid

Comment: i think i'm doing something wrong in adding Sublayer inside my grid